# Using sound file as pyaudio input device

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

With PyAudio it is fairly simple to open an input stream comming from a physical sound input device.

I wonder if there is a way of open an existing sound file as a stream, which has the same properties as the sound-device-stream?

Instead of

```
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    self.inStream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                channels=1,
                                rate=self.RATE,
                                input=True,
                                frames_per_buffer=self.BUFFERSIZE)
```

I'd like to do

```
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    self.inStream = self.p.open('testfile.wav',
                                input=True,
                                frames_per_buffer=self.BUFFERSIZE)
```

Regards,
Torsten

Comment: Why not just refactor this into its own function?

Comment: Do you mean "adding functionality" to PyAudio?

Comment: No, in your own applcation. Just make a convenience function that has the interface that you want, which maps to PyAudio's way of doing it underneath.

Comment: I understand. But if there was a transparent emulation mode you could modify every PyAudio application easily to work with sound files instead of devices.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. I've seen the documentation.

Comment: I now tried to create a class `PyAudioFileStream`which has the same interface as `PyAudio.Stream`. This gave me some good results. I was able to use the wav-file in an PyAudio application by just replacing one line.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you mate :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't use PyAudio to open file directly, however it's possible to combine pyaudio and wave modules in case your app reroutes the processed sound to SoundFlower for example.

```
import pyaudio, wave

def open_stream(self):
        self.p_audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.file_source = wave.open('input.wav', 'rb')
        s_width = self.file_source.getsampwidth()
        format = self.p_audio.get_format_from_width(s_width)
        channels = self.file_source.getnchannels()
        rate = self.file_source.getframerate()
        self.stream = self.p_audio.open(format=format,
                                        channels=channels,
                                        rate=rate,
                                        frames_per_buffer=1024,
                                        input=False,
                                        output=True,
                                        output_device_index=detect_build_in_output_device_idx(self.p_audio),
                                        stream_callback=self.__recording_callback)


def __recording_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):

        # read frames
        in_data = self.file_source.readframes(frame_count)
        # decode frames
        left, right = audio_decode(in_data, self.file_source.getnchannels())
        # process frames
        left, right = self.core.process(left, right)
        # encode back
        processed_data = audio_encode((left, right))

        return processed_data, pyaudio.paContinue
```